# Fatal error: Class 'Kartparadigm_Theme_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\project1\app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, magento

Fatal error: Class '**Kartparadigm_Theme_Helper_Data**' not found in

> C:\wamp\www\project1\app\Mage.php on line 547

I got the above error when i login into magento admin panel after i install magento extensions from the following link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect.

Here the '**Kartparadigm_Theme**' is a plug-in name.

how clear this error and how run  Kartparadigm_Theme?

Comment: Can you check.. please Data.php is exit at Kartparadigm/Theme/Helper

Answer (score 0):

Basically Magento is trying to fetch this file which is missing or does not have enough access permissions - app/code/community/Kartparadigm/Theme/Helper/Data.php OR app/code/local/Kartparadigm/Theme/Helper/Data.php

Now you have to ensure that the file exists on this path or comment out the code(if it is no longer useful), which is trying to access this file.

Temporarily, you can goto app/etc/modules/ open Kartparadigm_Theme.xml and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>` . This will bring your admin panel back in working function but will disable the module causing issue.

Once you have the file on specified path you can enable the module again from app/etc/modules/Kartparadigm_Theme.xml by changing it back to 
`<active>true</active>`

Clear all caches and then check.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Is because of Compilation Enabled In Backend.

**Fix :**

`Go to System->Tools->Compilation` and disable compilation first

Run Compilation Process again to compile the Kartparadigm Extension file code.

Flush Cache in Cache Management.

I am Sure this will fix the issue